# Get the value of combined TDs of dynamically generated TRs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the values of inputs in a dynamically generated `tr` in to an array. How can I get the combined td values in an array?

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table style="width:100%" id="sub1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="myInpCls" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="1">value 1</option>
                <option value="2">value 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="myInpCls" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="3">value 3</option>
                <option value="4">value 4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var onClick = function() {
    var inputs = $("#sub1").find('.myInpCls');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var el = inputs[i];
        alert($(el).val());
    }   
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

I can pull input values using `.find('.myInpCls')`. How can I get the combined values here? Something like the array of `input1##value 1`, `input2##value 2` etc.

**UPDATE:**
I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/739/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop the `tr` and search for the `input` and `select`. Than you can do whatever you want to.

[Your updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/754/)

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $("#sub1 tr").each(function() {
        var input = $(this).find(".myInpCls").val() || 0,
            select = $(this).find(".mySelCls").val() || 0,
            value = parseInt(input) + parseInt(select);

        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.

Comment: I make it now from this. I just wanted to combine. Not exactly to add. Accepting the answer.

Comment: I think you need to use `toString()` on the select value in the above fiddle as this is resulting in `NaN`

Comment: Yes, saw that too @RoryMcCrossan. Just updated the fiddle and the answer to the used one.

Answer (score 2):

To create an array of the input values you can use `map()`:

```
var onClick = function() {
    var values = $('#sub1 .myInpCls').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    //use the values array here...
    console.log(values);
};
$('#button').click(onClick);
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/743/)

Comment: I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.

Comment: That's a separate issue really, as it should have been in the question originally. However you could do that by returning an object from `map()` which contains both values, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zhwxp7zj/

Comment: I am sorry, I failed to explain it properly. The code already pull this item. I mentioned in the last part that i need a value of all combined tds. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a bit. Note that my answer takes into account the case where a user doesn't fill up all fields.

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  var append_array = [];
  $("tr").each(function(){
    var input = $(this).find("input").val();
    var select = $(this).find("select").val();
    
    (input != '' ? append_array.push(input) : '');
    append_array.push(select);
  });
  console.log(append_array);
  return append_array;
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table style="width: 100%" id="sub1">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="myInpCls" type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="1">value 1</option>
                <option value="2">value 2</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="myInpCls" type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="3">value 3</option>
                <option value="4">value 4</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.

Comment: Then instead of appending the select and the input separately, make an intermediate variable that appends them both, and push it. I gave you the core...

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var onClick = function() {
   var result= [];
        var inputs = $("#sub1").find('.myInpCls');
        for(var i=0; i < inputs.length;i++){
                var el = inputs[i];
          result.push($(el).val());
          }   
   alert(result.join(","));
    };

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table style="width: 100%" id="sub1">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="myInpCls" type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="1">value 1</option>
                <option value="2">value 2</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="myInpCls" type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="mySelCls">
                <option value="3">value 3</option>
                <option value="4">value 4</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will give you comma separated values for the text boxes , I hope this is what you are looking for.

Please mark the answer if it works for you

Comment: I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```js
var onClick = function() {
  var inputs = $("#sub1").find('.myInpCls');
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var el = inputs[i];
    arr.push("input #" + i + ' : ' + $(el).val());
  }
  var selects = $("#sub1").find('.mySelCls');
  for (var j = 0; j < selects.length; j++) {
    var sel = selects[j];
    arr.push("select #" + j + ' : ' + $(sel).val());
  }
  alert(arr);
};
$('#button').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

<table style="width:100%" id="sub1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="myInpCls" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="mySelCls">
        <option value="1">value 1</option>
        <option value="2">value 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="myInpCls" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="mySelCls">
        <option value="3">value 3</option>
        <option value="4">value 4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a select box in the next td. I have to combine these 2 items. ie,the input value+corresponding select item.